# contacts not in navigator (Google Chrome 80)

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome, contacts, navigator

I'm trying to access the contacts list of a phone from a website built with React Typescript. I'm using this [contact picker API](https://web.dev/contact-picker/). The thing is that when I try to do:

`const contacts = await navigator.contacts.select(['name', 'email'], { multiple: true });`

I'm getting that `navigator.contacts` is undefined. Off course, this is because there is no `contacts` in `navigator` (I logged `navigator` to be sure of this). However, when I modified the code of [this demo](https://contact-picker.glitch.me/) (which works perfectly) to log navigator, I got that there `navigator.contacts` was NOT undefined. In both cases I used the same browser (and device) so I don't understand why I'm getting different results. Is it something with React? How can I solve this? Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you happen to find a solution yet? I'm having the same problem in Vue.js.

Comment: Hm, I think it might not be possible to use this inside any framework at all.

From the specs: "Furthermore, The API will only be available from secure top-level contexts." - https://github.com/WICG/contact-api#security-and-privacy

Comment: @Tafel nope, I just had to drop this approach :(

Comment: I actually dived more into this issue, and I think it indeed might have to do with top-level contexts. React (or any framework for that matter) CAN be secure top-level contexts. But you have to serve it over HTTPS for example and a couple of other things. Read more about it here: https://www.w3.org/TR/secure-contexts/#examples-top-level